# Java - Using multiple PrintWriter but saves only last println

Tags: java, file-io

I'm designing a program to split data stored in a text file into two separate files based on the label of that data.

Here is a small version of that data.

```
0,1,2,normal. 
5,5,5,strange.
2,1,3,normal.
```

I use a class to store each line as a sample. The class parses the line to store the last value as the label. I encapsulated each line as an object, because I intend to add features later.

Here is code for the `Sample` class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {
    String[]str_vals = new String[3];
    String label;
    Sample(Scanner line) {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            str_vals[i] = line.next();
        }
        label = line.next();
    }
    String getValsForCSV() {
        StringBuilder retval = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            retval.append(str_vals[i]).append(",");
        }
        retval.append(label).append(".");
        return retval+"";
    }
    String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Below is the code in question. My `Separator` class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Separator {
    public static final String DATAFILE = "src/etc/test.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        runData();
    }
    public static void runData() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(DATAFILE))) {
            // kddcup file uses '.\n' at end of each line
            // setting this as delimiter which will consume the period
            in.useDelimiter("[.]\r\n|[.]\n|\n");
            Sample curr;
            while(in.hasNext()) {
                // line will hold all fields for a single sample
                Scanner line = new Scanner(in.next());
                line.useDelimiter(", *");
                curr = new Sample(line);
                try (
                    PrintWriter positive = new PrintWriter(new File(DATAFILE+"-pos"));
                    PrintWriter negative = new PrintWriter(new File(DATAFILE+"-neg"));
                ) {
                    if (curr.getLabel().equals("normal")) {
                        positive.println("GOOD");
                    } else {
                        negative.println("BAD");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This issue that I am experiencing is that the code only saves the last `Sample` seen to its respective file. So with above data the `test.txt-neg` will be empty and `test.txt-pos` will have a single line `GOOD`; it does not have two `GOOD`'s as expected.

If I modify the `test.txt` data to include only the first two lines, then the files states are reversed (i.e. `test.txt-neg` has `BAD` and `test.txt-pos` is empty). Could someone please explain to me what is going on, and how to fix this error?

Comment: You are creating a new `PrintWriter` everytime through the loop. You can either append to the file, or move the initialization outside of the loop. The reason you only see the last one is that you **overwrite** the file everytime through the loop.

Comment: Pass in the `PrintWriter`(s) or open a new outputstream in append mode.

Comment: OMG that is what I get for trying to program with no sleep for 24 hours. Thank you. I'm new two stackoverflow, should I just delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Because the error was pointed out in a comment.  I wanted to give credit to KevinO and Elliott Frisch for the solution.

As mentioned, I'm creating a new `PrintWriter` each time and creating the `PrintWriter` in it's default mode of overwriting a file.  As a result it always saves both files based on a single sample.

To correct this error, I have pulled out the instantiations of the `PrintWriter` to be in the try-with-resource block of the `Scanner` object

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Separator {
    public static final String DATAFILE = "src/etc/test.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        runData();
    }
    public static void runData() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(DATAFILE));
            PrintWriter positive = new PrintWriter(new File(DATAFILE+"-pos"));
            PrintWriter negative = new PrintWriter(new File(DATAFILE+"-neg"));
        ) {
            // kddcup file uses '.\n' at end of each line
            // setting this as delimiter which will consume the period
            in.useDelimiter("[.]\r\n|[.]\n|\n");
            Sample curr;
            while(in.hasNext()) {
                // line will hold all fields for a single sample
                Scanner line = new Scanner(in.next());
                line.useDelimiter(", *");
                curr = new Sample(line);
                if (curr.getLabel().equals("normal")) {
                    positive.println("GOOD");
                } else {
                    negative.println("BAD");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```